# Make global object available inside for loop nodejs 10 Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, iot

I have this Google Cloud Function, I've deleted some useless parts for the example.

What I want is to have  **app.cloudRegion**, **app.projectId** etc. available at **const setDeviceConfig** inside the for loop.

My guess is I'm missing some fat arrow somewhere but I'm not sure where.

```
exports.newFirmware = async (file) => {
    var app = {};
    const str = file.name;
    const bucketName = file.bucket;
    const binaryName = str.substring(0, str.length - 4);
    app.cloudRegion = '1';
    app.projectId = '2';
    app.registryId = '3';
    app.iotClient = new app.iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient({});
    app.parentName = app.iotClient.registryPath(app.projectId, cloudRegion, app.registryId);
    try {
        const responses = await app.iotClient.listDevices({
            parent: app.parentName
        });
        const devices = responses[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            const setDeviceConfig = (app.iotClient, bla, app.registryId, app.projectId, app.cloudRegion, bla, bla) => {
                const formattedName = iotClient.devicePath(projectId, app.cloudRegion, registryId, deviceId);               
                const binaryData = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
    
                try {
                    const responses = await iotClient.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(request);                    
                } catch (err) {                   
                    ....
                }
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        ....
    }
};
```

**edit:**

```
    try {
    const responses = await app.iotClient.listDevices({
        parent: app.parentName
    });       
    const devices = responses[0];
    console.log(app.data);  
    for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {            
        const device = devices[i];
        console.log(device.id);
        setDeviceConfig(app.iotClient, device.id, app.registryId, app.projectId, app.cloudRegion, app.data, binaryName)
    }
            const setDeviceConfig = async (iotClient, deviceId, registryId, projectId, cloudRegion, data, version) => {               
            const formattedName = iotClient.devicePath(projectId, cloudRegion, registryId, deviceId);
            console.log('formattedName --> ' + formattedName)
            const binaryData = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
            const request = {
                name: formattedName,
                versionToUpdate: version,
                binaryData: binaryData,
            };
            try {
                const responses = await iotClient.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(request);
                console.log('Success:', responses[0]);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Could not update config:', deviceId);
                console.error('Message:', err);
            }               
        };
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Could not list devices', err);
}
```

Comment: The params passed to the function setDeviceConfig cannot have dot notation -> `iceConfig = (app.iotClient` that is syntacticly incorrect. So change it to `const setDeviceConfig = (iotClient,` and call the function like so `setDeviceConfig(app.iotClient` and that applies to all `app.xxx` not just the one i shown.

Comment: I've edited by adding what you said (or what I understood) and now I get: Could not list devices ReferenceError: setDeviceConfig is not defined

Comment: My mistake, I was sending an empty field. Thanks.